# Shrinkwrap modifier problems

Tags: shrinkwrap

I am trying to shrink wrap the images to the spine of the book. It worked for one book so I duplicated the book. When I moved the books the shrink wrap stopped working. I cannot get the image to shrink wrap around the spine again. I have delete the modification and tried again by have not been able to get it to work regardless of the settings that I choose. Any ideas how to get it to shrink wrap around the spine and then follow the book as I move it around.

[image]

Comment: You could parent the object to the book? If it still doesn't work please share your file

Comment: You should not use unnecessary geometry if you only need a texture. You should make a UV map and place your texture on the object using materials.

Comment: I disagree, this method is pretty widely used to add decals on objects, you are making assumptions on the OP's workflow. Maybe they don't care about adding a few vertices or they can't use UV maps for a specific reason.

Comment: I did parent the object but obviously unsuccessful. I do not know how to use UV mapping. I was just trying to learn the Shrink Wrap skill. Just thought it would be a simple task but as with everything Blender its more complicated than the videos show you.

Comment: Did you try applying all transforms?

Comment: I have started over and it worked, kind of. If I move the book the shrink wraps follow but I have to move the book though as moving the shrink map does only moves the shrinkwrap and not the book but at least it is mostly working.  I have applied all transforms.

Comment: @Gorgious, just because lots of people do it, doesn't mean they should... In any case. That's why it's a comment, not an answer. What is the reason not to use regular workflow with texturing here? Mr R McWilliams, maybe you could clarify?

Comment: Sorry, did not see the comment before. The reason is because they don't yet know how to use UV mapping. In that case my advice is valid. UV Mapping will be easier and is the standard solution in these cases.

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys the reason for not using regular workflow with texturing here is because that would indicate that I know what I'm doing which I don't. The problem with seeking some advice from experts is that you get different answers and even then the answers are written for other experts and not people like me who are trying to learn something new.

Comment: I think you should look into UV mapping.